# ScrollViewer scroll changed occurs continuously

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, scrollviewer

I have a data grid wherein each row has multiple row details. Because of the need of virtualization and because the data in the nested grid is huge (row details), I had to enable an internal scroll bar for each of the row details grid.

Everything seems to be working fine except that sometimes I see the scroll viewer scroll changed occurring continuously and never stops. I have subscribed to this event to dynamically set a max height for my row details grid's to enable/disable the internal scroll bar.

I am unable to find the issue for this. What could be the problem??

Comment: if you just write diagnostic trace in the scroll changed event handler, not set the max height of the grid, will it solve the problem? I doubt setting max height fires more scroll changed events.

Comment: Hi kennyzx,
If i don't set the Max Row Height then the scroll viewer assumes PositiveInfinity and scroll bar will never be shown. Should I just write the diagnostic trace?? Sorry I don't think I got you clearly.

I tried other few things, instead of scroll viewer scroll changed, i tried the same for the vertical scroll bar inside (I traversed the logical tree to find it out). It stops this series of event triggers but somehow the scrolling smoothness is gone.

Any idea. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I found another small issue with the horizontal scroll bar, When user drags the vertical scroll quickly to the end I see the horizontal scroll shifting few pixels to the left. This doesn't look nice and hides my internal scroll bar. What could this issue possibly be?

Comment: could you post your code (minimal code that can reproduce the issue), it is easier if have some code to understand the real issue.

Comment: Sure, give me some time, I will create a sample and post the same.
Thanks